# Date type and format swagger in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, swagger, swagger-php

i am using swagger documentation to chow api data, i one of my case i want to get data from database by a specific date, get a day by a $day variable i use a method and working fine in Postman
in postman :
[image]

But in swagger i dont know how i can add parameter $day in swagger

my code work fine :

```
public function getdatabydate() {
    $p = "zero";
    $day = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime($_GET['day']));
    $users = DB::select('select * from S where (`timestamp` like "'.$day.'%")' );
    if (!$users){
        return $p;
    }
    return $users;


    }
```

In swagger :

```
/**
     * @OA\Get(
     *
     *   path="/api/getdatabydate",
     *   summary="Get weather",
     *   @OA\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="successful operation",
      *   ),
      * @OA\Parameter(
 *    description="Date day",
 *    in="header",
 *    name="day",
 *    required=true,
 *    @OA\Schema(
 *       type="string",
 * format ="date-time",
 *    )
 * ),
     *     security={
     *         {"bearerAuth": {}}
     *     }
     * ),
     */
```

Comment: Replace `in="header"` with `in="query"` and `format="date-time"` with `format="date"`. Does this help?

Comment: thanks u ! worked :)))))))))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `in="header"` with `in="query"` and `format="date-time"` with `format="date"`.